# @nuxtjs/style-resources not importing scss files

Tags: sass, nuxt.js

The @nuxtjs/style-resources module isn't importing my scss files. I have a special folder structure to generate multiple websites from one Nuxt project, I think this might cause the problem.

This is what my folder structure looks like:

```
/
package.json
  /src
    /site-one
    /site-two
    /shared
      nuxt.config.js
      /assets
        /scss
          imports.scss
```

This is what my nuxt.config file in /shared looks like:

```
modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
],

styleResources: {
  scss: [
      './assets/scss/imports.scss',
  ]
},
```

I tried `'~assets/scss/imports.scss'` without success.

I also tried making an alias like so:

```
build: {
  ...
  extend(config, ctx) {
    config.resolve.alias['~sharedPath'] = __dirname
  }
}
```

and using a path like this: `'~sharedPath/assets/scss/imports.scss'` but that doesn't seem to work either.

I'm not sure what else I can try to make @nuxtjs/style-resources import my scss files, please help.

Answer (score 4):

I fixed it like so:

```
modules: [
  '@nuxtjs/style-resources',
],

styleResources: {
  scss: [
    __dirname + '/assets/scss/imports.scss',
  ]
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Short syntax of passing in config didn't work for me:

Does not work:

```
 modules:[
    [
      '@nuxtjs/style-resources', {
           scss: [ "~css/variables.scss"],
       }
    ]
]
```

Works:

```
modules: ["@nuxtjs/style-resources"],

  styleResources: {
    scss: ["~css/variables.scss"]
  },
```